# MVC, reduce coupling between Gui and core packages

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, coupling

I my program I use MVC pattern by having gui and core package that consist of several classes. To reduce coupling between the core classes and Gui package all classes communicate with Gui package through coordinating class Facade that is in a core package.
In Gui package I have a main Frame class that adds  other  Jpanels depending on the “phase” of the application. For example LoginPanel is replaced with MenuPanel after user has logged in. All those panels are declared as a separate classes extending JPanel.
The question is, should I use some coordinating class in Gui package that will communicate with the Facade coordinating class in core package? At this stage my frame or Jpanels sends messages to a coordinating class in the core package and Im thinking if its good idea to reduce coupling by Gui package having also coordinating class, that will on behalf frame and other JPanels communicate with core class.

Comment: The question depends a lot on the implementation details. At some point, you need to have some kind of "idea" of how you're communicating with the various aspects of your code, they need to be able to talk with each other, what you want to do is make it as easy as possible to change the underlying implementation of those APIs/classes without the need to change the classes which use them. There are various techniques you can use depending on what you want to achieve. Remember, Swing is already (a type) of MVC, there's nothing stopping you from wrapping it again in another layer though

Answer (score 0):

This response is not about Swing practice, but a general approach to avoid coupling and increase cohesion.

To Reduce Coupling,
You need to follow 2 strategies as per Standard Java without any frameworks in place :

```
1. Code to Interfaces instead of Concrete implementations
2. Try to implement Factory design pattern
```